# How can I link styles.scss file with django templates?

Tags: django

I just facing a silly problem. I can't link ***styles.scss*** file with django template from the static folder. This method not working here **{% static '/css/style.scss' %}**. Now, what will have to do for linking **.scss file**?

Comment: Did you {%load static%}?

Comment: yes, I did... The issue already I solved. I had to install django-scss.